# Transparency in composite controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I have a composite control that is includes a groupbox control. The problem is it covers the controls that are placed on top of this composite control. Even though I send the new controls to top, so they should be visible, but they aren't.

When I just use the groupbox, of course it shows through things so you see the included controls, just outlined by the groupbox.

Should I have to do something to get the same effect/behaviour in a composite control?

EDIT: Left side shows the control in the designer, right side shows the control at runtime.

[image]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the designer, showing where your controls should be?  If they are hidden, you might draw an outline of where they *should* be visible.  It might help clarify your problem for the rest of us.

Comment: If you move the button over an edge of your control - what happens to the button? If the part of it that is outside the control is still visible, then your control is not behaving like a container. But if it gets clipped --- then your control is working like a contatiner - in the designer at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible Quintin is right, and that something is going wrong with the designer support of your control, that is, you've created ControlA, and are extending it to ControlB by adding a button at design time.  When you instatiate ControlB, the button is not visible.

Can you verify at runtime, using breakpoints/asserts/etc that:`

1. `ChildButton` exists.
2. `ChildButton` is a member of `CompositeControl.Controls`.
3. `ChildButton` location is 'in-view' of the `CompositeControl`.
4. `ChildButton` is visible.

If it were me, I'd set a breakpoint in the constructor of the control, and ride into `InitializeComponent()`, checking that everything is created and added correctly.  If `ChildButton` exists, and has a reference in `CompositeControl.Controls` and its location is in-view, then I'm at a loss to explain why it's not showing.

Comment: Thanks, if I am not wrong, you are thinking ChildButton is part of the composite control? Because it's not. The composite control is made up of 2 controls: 1 checkbox, 1 groupbox. But later when I use this composite control and place some controls on it, as a user, the controls only show up at the top at design time.

Comment: Yes, I knew you meant that.  I'm starting to think designer support for your control is broken.  When you step through the code as your CompositeControl is initialized, check that everything should be as you expect.  As a last resort, you could try adding the button to your control at runtime, to verify that it does show correctly.  If it does, then you know you've got a designer issue.

Comment: Thanks, if it's a designer issue, would it be fixed?

Comment: If you've implemented Quintin's suggestion, there's not much more that I can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are meaning that you would like the custom control to behave like a container (like a groupbox normally does) then you need to let the control and the designer know how it should be treated.

Remember to implement [`IContainerControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.icontainercontrol(VS.71).aspx) and decorate the object with the appropriate designer attribute for designer container support IE:

```
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner,System.Design", typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesigner))]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also useful. But for my problem, it behaves like a groupbox, but it covers the controls inside of it. I can see them in the designer but when you run the tool, they appear behind the composite control.